# How to apply string split function on multiple columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, string, split

I have a data like this, please help

```
id  | name    | value
----+---------+---------
1   | a, b    | 12, 34
```

I want to get an output like this:

```
id  | name  | value
----+-------+---------
 1  | a     |  12  
 1  | b     |  34
```

Comment: FYI: you might consider normalizing your table.  Then you wouldn't have to do these types of splits.

Comment: Are those comma separated strings always pairs? Or can there be more than 2 items e.g. name of "a, b, c" and value of "12, 43, 56"

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49655621/using-string-split-to-create-rows-from-multiple-columns

Comment: paul: they aren't always in pairs , if we have 100 rows, some rows contain only 1 value, some contain 2, some contain 3, so its not Static,

Answer (score 1):

Just another option (Gordon is way too fast for me)

The JSON [Key] is a proper sequence... assuming both columns have the same number of elements.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([id] varchar(50),[name] varchar(50),[value] varchar(50))  
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'a,b','12,34')
 
Select ID
      ,Name  = max(case when Item='Name'  then B.Value end)
      ,Value = max(case when Item='Value' then B.Value end)
From @YourTable A
Cross Apply (
                Select [Key]
                      ,Item = 'Name'
                      ,Value
                 From  OpenJSON( '["'+replace(replace([name],'"','\"'),',','","')+'"]' )
                Union All
                Select [Key]
                      ,Item = 'Value'
                      ,Value
                 From  OpenJSON( '["'+replace(replace([value],'"','\"'),',','","')+'"]' )

             ) B
 Group By ID,[Key]
```

**Results**

```
ID  Name    Value
1   a       12
1   b       34
```

Comment: john: this works for the scenario mentioned above, but in reality i have 10 columns having values seperated by a delimiter

Comment: @Babyboy It would still work... you would just need to add 8 more UNION ALL's.  It would get a little ugly, but there is always a penalty for design flaws.

Answer (score 0):

One method is a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select id, convert(varchar(max), null) as name, convert(varchar(max), null) as val, 
             convert(varchar(max), names + ',') as names, convert(varchar(max), vals + ',') as vals
      from t
      union all
      select id,
             convert(varchar(max), left(names, charindex(',', names) - 1)),
             convert(varchar(max), left(vals, charindex(',', vals) - 1)),
             convert(varchar(max), stuff(names, 1, charindex(',', names), '')),
             convert(varchar(max), stuff(vals, 1, charindex(',', vals), ''))
      from cte
      where names like '%,%' and vals like '%,%'
     )
select id, name, val
from cte
where name is not null;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c59e03e856da6975ec53e7480652b3fb) is a db<>fiddle.